# Access is denied while reading excel file in ASP.net using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I am writing web application using ASP.net (C#). I have one excel file on server which I want to read. When I try to read this excel file using below code then it throws exception. I have provided full rights to user (IIS User) on server for particular folder where excel file kept.

Reading Logic:

```
Excel.Application xlApp = null;
Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = null;
Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = null;
Excel.Range range = null;

xlApp = new Excel.Application();
xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Uploads\data.xls);
xlWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkbook.Worksheets.get_Item(sheetName);
range = xlWorksheet.get_Range("A1", "B5");
```

Exception:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following
>   error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005
>   (E_ACCESSDENIED)).

Can you please help me to understand this error?

Answer (score 2):

Office automation [is not supported from inside IIS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757) or any other situation where the code is running outside of a user session (for example a windows service). In the linked knowledge base you can see you are getting "Message 4" in the "Problems using server-side Automation of Office" section.

If it is possible to switch from `.xls` to `.xlsx` files you can use [Microsoft's Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx) to open and manipulate office 2007 and newer files.

If you must use the legacy file format of `.xls` you will need to find a 3rd party library that can support it.